# IIS cache retries

Tags: .net, http, caching, iis, iis-6

I am sending an HTTP request to a DNS on IIS 6.1, the request should insert 50,000 records in a SQL table, the request timeouts and none of the records are inserted. However, the IIS is retrying the same request from its cache, so every 10 min the same 50,000 records are inserted in the table.

Note that the POST request is fired from a .NET console application using JSON format.

Comment: So, what is the question? What do you mean sending requests to DNS? Why does the IIS retry requests? It does not make sense...

Comment: I'm assuming you're hitting the server directly and there is no load balancer in between? It will be helpful if you can post code as well

Comment: I have the same problem as you. Trying to send 500k records into the DB ( On a UDT ). Then selecting data joined with the data I sent, it timeouts after 5m and the IIS retries. I have no clue, where to change this. What have you done to increase the timeout and where comes the retries?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell exactly what you are asking or to give a response that could programatically solve your issue but I do have some general observations.

Maybe you could send less records in each request so the request doesn't time out and get cached/retried.

You could also make one of the columns in the SQL table a primary key or require it to be unique so if the caching/retry issue does occur you will not end up with duplicate records.

If you have access to the IIS and correct permissions you may be able to disable the caching: https://forums.iis.net/t/959070.aspx?How+do+you+disable+caching+in+IIS+